# how to stream text into html from remote log file - ruby on rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have this ruby on rails app that execute any command via ssh on a remote linux host when a button is pressed.It then returns the output with Jquery and display it in my html page.

However, if I want to start a Weblogic server,I have no way for telling the user when the server is up and running because it writes into a log file and my Jquery returns only when the Jquery is done.

My question is : is there a way to stream in my html page the output of a command like : tail -f somefile.log until a particular word is written (exemple : "server : running")

OR

Is there a way that,after executing startWeblogic.sh, my jquery read the log file and wait for "server : running" then returns with a success message.

I hope this is something I can do! thank you guys for your answers.

Here is my current configuration :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("button").click(function (event) {
    $.post("/ssh/execute", {
    hostname: $('#serverlist').val(),
    username: $('#login').val(),
    password: $('#password').val(),
    command: $('#CommandSelect').val(),

    }).done(function (data){
        $("#textarea").text(data.retour);
    }).fail(function (data){
        $("#textarea").text("Wrong password or the server exploded");
    });
});

});
```

Here is my controller :

```
class SshController < ApplicationController
    def execute

        require 'rubygems'
        require 'net/ssh'

        hostname = params[:hostname]
        username = params[:username]
        password = params[:password]
        if params[:command] == "ls"
            cmd =  "sudo su - -c 'ls -lart '"
        else
        cmd =params[:command]
        end


        Net::SSH.start(hostname, username, :password => password) do |ssh|
            render :json => {:retour => ssh.exec!(cmd)}
        end

    end
end
```

Comment: does `ssh.exec` stream the output or does not exit till the command is finished?

Comment: You will have to pass a in block if you want to stream the command output. Example: `ssh.exec!("tail -f /var/log/syslog") do |channel, stream, data|`

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Why don't you just try to check whether the service has been started or not using `ps` ?

You could run `ps -elf | grep java` on the server every 30 seconds for instance, and then you could see if the particular instance you are looking for is running.

I think that would be much more efficient than constantly reading the log file in streaming.

Comment: Great suggestion but if the server crash at start it lacks informations for the user.I  will try your other suggestion

Comment: Polling (especially polling by starting a pipeline of connected subprocesses, reading that pipeline's stdout, and wait()ing for them to exit -- as this suggestion does -- at a regular interval) is considerably _less_ efficient than being proactively notified by the OS when a subprocess exits (as by a wait() call), or when a file is closed (as by inotify() and kin); in both of these cases, by contrast, a process can be completely idle while waiting, and will have no extra latency added by a poll interval.

Comment: Also, waiting to start the transfer until output is completely generated increases the total time for content to be sent to the client.

Answer (score 7):

To build on-top of @emaillenin 's answer, you certainly can use `tail` with the `--follow` option to consume the file as it grows. Even better, you can follow the file **name** via `-F`, which is helpful if the file name changes over time (eg: `MyLog.log` gets moved to `MyLog1.log` at the end of the day). More information about `tail` is available at your appropriate man (1) page, or you can reference [this generic Tail man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/tail.1.html).

```
`tail -F /var/log/MyApplication.log`
```

Combine this with Rails 4's [`ActionController::Live` streaming over HTTP](http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Live.html) and [`Open3`'s `#popen3` method,](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/open3/rdoc/Open3.html#method-c-popen3) and you can run tail continuously in a background process until the user closes their window!

Note: You'll need to use a server which handles concurrency well, like [Puma.](http://puma.io/) 1 worker per open connection is the rule.

```
require 'open3'

class StaticPagesController < ApplicationController
  include ActionController::Live

  private

  def follow_log
    begin
      stdin, stdout, stderr, wait_thread = Open3.popen3("tail -F -n 0 #{Rails.root.join('log', 'development.log')}")

      stdout.each_line do |line|
        yield line
      end

    rescue IOError

    ensure
      stdin.close
      stdout.close
      stderr.close
      Process.kill('HUP', wait_thread[:pid])
      logger.info("Killing Tail pid: #{wait_thread[:pid]}")
    end
  end
end
```

Here, we're executing the `tail` command in a sub-process, and making sure it starts at the bottom of the file with the `-n 0` option. This means it's always waiting for the initial line, and will not print previous lines that the user may have already seen in another session.

Every time a new line gets added, we'll `yield` that to a block, so that we can write it out to the stream.

We also `ensure` that at the end of the block, we close all of the open IO streams, and send a `HUP` kill command to the process.

Now, we can build our action:

```
  def home
    begin
      follow_log do |line| 
        response.stream.write line
      end

    rescue IOError

    ensure
      logger.info("Killing stream")
      response.stream.close
    end
  end
```

The `IOError` will be raised once response.stream.write tries to write to a stream that no longer exists (ie: the user closed their browser). This has one  drawback: the method will keep `tail` running until the next line is written to the file. Depending on your log, that could be a long time.

Answer (score 2):

To do live streaming to webpages from Rails, you need to use [ActionController::Live](http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Live.html)

A simple example:

```
class MyController < ActionController::Base
  include ActionController::Live

  def stream
    response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'text/event-stream'
    100.times {
      response.stream.write "hello world\n"
      sleep 1
    }
  ensure
    response.stream.close
  end
end
```

For client side streaming, use [EventSource](http://html5please.com/#eventsource) and have a look at an [example](http://blogs.sequoiainc.com/blogs/easy-streams-with-rails-4-actioncontroller-live).

To make SSH commands work with streaming, you could poll the server multiple times with a gap of 2 seconds and stream the output.

Comment: Thank you , I will try this if Pierre-Olivier's suggestion does not work for me !